# Getting postal address from Facebook login button

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I've gone through the Facebook help on adding a login button to your site. I've added loads before without any problem but  this time I want to be able to get a user's address so that orders can be despatched to them.

Ideally I'd also like to ask them if they would like to subscribe to our email or sms marketing list too. Although this isn't that important at the moment.

So far I've got this:

`<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_address,user_city,user_hometown,user_zip,country" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>`
but it doesn't load anything. If I remove user_city, user_zip and country it works but doesn't get the user address.

I know that I'll need to get Facebook to approve it but if it's possible I'd like to get this info from Facebook

Comment: Not, that is not possible – the postal address of a user is not available via API.

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought might be the case, is there a way around it int rems of can I get as much info as possible, city, state, zip, country etc then when somebody places an order they are then prompted to enter the rest?

Comment: What info is possible available you find described in the documentation. However it is rather unlikely that Facebook will approve your app to ask for all the required permissions.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I guess I need to rethink this